# git push error:fatal: unable to access .....Port number ended with 'a'

Tags: git, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, pytorch-lightning

I finetuned the t5 model and I want to upload it on my hugging face library.
I have my directory, where I save tokenizer and model.

```
tokenizer.save_pretrained('my-t5-qa-legal')
trained_model.model.save_pretrained('my-t5-qa-legal')
```

Here are files in my directory:

```
!ls

config.json    special_tokens_map.json  tokenizer_config.json
pytorch_model.bin  spiece.model
```

I logged in my account with:

```
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login

notebook_login()

!sudo apt-get install git-lfs
!transformers-cli repo create my-t5-qa-legal
!git config --global user.email my email
!git config --global user.name "my_user_name"
!git init
!git add .
!git commit -m "Initial commit"
!git remote add origin https://my_user_name:password@huggingface.co/my_user_name/my-t5-qa-legal
!git push  --set-upstream origin master
```

but this gives me the error:

```
fatal: unable to access .....Port number ended with 'a'
```

Comment: If you literally used `my_user_name:password` it would have worked. But your password has `#` or `:` in it, so it didn't work. You must encode special characters here. See https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1909 for example.

Comment: It's much better for security to use a credential manager for storing credentials and not put them in the URL.  In addition, it avoids this problem entirely.